# Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid - Windows 10

Tags: python, cmake

Upon opening Cmake, I set the "Where is the source code" to

> C:/Users/myname/Documents/folder/folder1/folder2/python-codes/GMXExec/GMXExec/Gromacs506

and "Where to build the binaries" to

> C:/Users/myname/Documents/folder/folder1/folder2/python-codes/GMXExec/build

I just followed the step-by-step "Install" instructions for gromacs. I can't get past this because of the error message in the title.

Gromacs version is 5.0.6
CMake version is 3.10.2
Windows 10

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here is the error message in red below

> CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Users/SamanthaAngela/Documents/escuela/chem/kowd/python-codes/GMXExec/GMXExec/Gromacs506" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
>   Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

Help me, I just want to run some .gro files.

Comment: The error message is clear - the folder, which you pass to `cmake` as a source directory, doesn't contain `CMakeLists.txt` file, which CMake wants to see.

Comment: it's asking for the source of gromacs right? not cmake?

Comment: Yes, its asks for source directory with gromacs, which contains `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: maybe write how do you set the "where"s or how you invoke cmake